# Marmalade CEventCallback

Tags: c++, c++11, события, callback

Привет всем! 
Помогите,кто может,разобраться со спецификой работы CEventCallback в Marmalade SDK.

Я создал 2 класса, GUIElement(prt) и SceneOne(derived). В потомке мне необходимо дернуть один из методов базового класса по событию клика по кнопке.

Но у меня что-то не получается создать адекватный кастомный обработчик... В примерах в m2kit, в разделе кнопки, разработчики сделали такую функцию в main():

```
 void btnClicked() { /*some code*/ }
```

Тоесть функция не является членом какого-то класса, просто объявлена в зоне видимости. И в мейне просто передают ее в качестве аргумента в :

```
btn->SubscribeEvent(BUTTON_CLICK, btnClicked);
```

И все корректно работает.

Но моя программа должна быть несколько сложнее =) Мне необходимо создать свой обработчик,принадлежащий классу SceneOne, но я постоянно наталкиваюсь на ошибку.

```
argument of type "void (SceneOne::*)(m2dkit::core::CEventArgs *args)" is incompatible with parameter of type "m2dkit::core::CEventCallback"
```

Пробовал так же передавать такой вариант как колбэк, но результата не давало ибо нет возможности привести к нужному типу функцию :

```
std::bind(&SceneOne::btnPressed, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Доп инфа : Scene - http://prntscr.com/bx9np4 | http://prntscr.com/bx9nz7

UPD: Когда я делаю метод обработчик статическим - он принимается корректно в SubscribeEvent, но тогда из статик функции нельзя дергать НЕ статик методы.
Получается есть 2 пути и в обоих проблема...

Comment: Один из вариантов решения проблемы - передавать в static метод указатель на экземпляр класса, и в нем через него дернуть уже не static метод.

Comment: А если сам статический хендлер имеет сигнатуру void (CEventCallBack)(CEventArgs*) , то как прокинуть свой доп параметр,являющийся указателем?
Ведь метод отработает по клику и примет CEventArgs* args в себя

Comment: А где можно посмотреть на `CEventArgs` можете ссылку дать?

Comment: CEventArgs - http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/structCEventArgs.html

CEventCallBack -  http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/group__eventsgroup.html#ga25e223dcde653ea27e55d39e6d1b8a02

Comment: Кажется там даже проще, поле `m_Source` в `args` обработчика,  это ваш `btn` вроде.

Comment: Извините,но что-то я не до понял Вас. Мне через btn тогда из m_Source достучаться до парента и вызвать метод необходимый мне?

Comment: Ну если нужный обработчик находится в родителе btn, то получается так.

Comment: Да,Вы были абсолютно правы!

`CButtonEventPressedArgs* arguments = (CButtonEventPressedArgs*)args;

CButton* button = (CButton*)arguments->m_Source;

SceneTwo* parent = (SceneTwo*)button->GetParent();
parent->showNextScreen();`

Спасло положение)
Большое спасибо за содействие и много плюсов Вам в карму)

Comment: Да пожалуйста. Напишите ответ, чтобы другим удобнее было найти.

Answer (score 1):

Решением являлось вытягивание ссылки на парента из кнопки.

```
//definition in .h class
static void btnClickHandler(CEventArgs*);


btn->SubscribeEvent(BUTTON_EVENT_RELEASED, btnClickHandler);


void SceneOne::btnClickHandler(CEventArgs* args)
{
    CButtonEventPressedArgs* arguments = (CButtonEventPressedArgs*)args;
    CButton* button = (CButton*)arguments->m_Source;
    SceneOne* parent = (SceneOne*)button->GetParent();
    parent->showNextScreen();
}
```

Исходя из этого, ответом на вопрос является выбор в сторону создания статического метода в котором дергаем не статик функции через парента.

Спасибо за помощь, @Vladimir Gamalian